# Google APIs for Android 5.0

Tags: android

I started to learn android app development and try to download necessary platforms from sdk manager. When I choose packages to download in API 21, there is Google APIs packages, and I am wondering about what these are? Should I download them as a beginner to android? Any documentation on Google APIs will be very helpful, if you share with me.

Also I have another question, I read from android developer site about sdk platforms [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html), it says you should download latest android api(which is 21 in my case) and the lowest api(which is 14 for me) you want to support. Should I download the package between these two apis for making apps that support them as well. Or will they be enough? I am asking this question because in the videos I watched, they installed other packages too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I download the Google APIs as a beginner to Android?

No, you don't need to download the Google APIs option. Usually you only need to compile against the Google APIs if you are developing with an emulator and you are using Google Play Services in your app (or something similar).

> Should I download the package between API 14 and API 21 for making apps that support them as well?

No, you only need to download the API that matches your `compileSdkVersion` (so in your case, you only need to download API 21... this will also provide support for earlier API versions as well).

Comment: Actually, you need to download the API that matches your `compileSdkVersion`. `targetSdkVersion` does not require anything special to be downloaded from SDK Manager.